# How do I make a connection to a database with Hibernate, Java, and Gradle?

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle, orm

I can't make a connection to my database with Hibernate and Gradle with Java, and I am getting the error below. What am I doing wrong?

> error: cannot access Referenceable
> Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
> ^   class file for javax.naming.Referenceable not found

**Main Class**

```java
public class App{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
            Metadata meta = new MetadataSources(ssr).getMetadataBuilder().build();
            SessionFactory sessions = meta.buildSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessions.openSession();
            Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
            t.commit();
            session.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**module-info.java**

```java
module PhoneBook {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;


    exports app;
}
```

**Gradle dependencies**

```
implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.25'
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.5.7.Final'
```

Comment: Just an FYI, but adding in versions for the tags you list is always helpful to anyone wanting to help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using Java 9 or higher?  If so, it sounds like
you are missing requires java.naming; directive in the module-info.java of the  module, that accesses Referenceable. Adding this directive should fix it:

```java
module YourModule {
   requires java.naming;
   ...
}
```

Comment: i tried it before and he give me another error

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    java.sql.SQLException`

Comment: Then your versions are not compatible with your msSQL connector, Hibernate, and JAVA (I haven't checked) or your classpaths are not setup properly or you have typo(s) in your declarations.  You need to check all three.

Comment: @Moka You will also need to add `requires java.sql`. You might be better off not using modular Java, and revert back to plain-old class-path based Java. As far as I know, Hibernate is not yet modularized, and neither is MySQL Connector/J, so you'll likely be playing whack-a-mole for each and every dependency.

Comment: @Mark Tottenveel I hadn't thought about the possible issues with modular code, yes it would be a lot more straight-forward using JAVA 8.

Comment: You can also do it in recent versions of Java, modules are optional, so it doesn't necessitate reverting back to Java 8.

Comment: Thanks guys, I deleted the module and i used the old version of hibernate and it works now

Comment: Great, thanks for letting us know what worked!  You might want to add the result to the bottom of your question or answer your own question so people will find it easier.